# trouble retrieving account status after login with paypal

Tags: php, authentication, paypal

I have been trying to use the Login with Paypal to verify sellers email and account for our website.

### This is what I am currently using and it seems to work partially ...

```
##########################################################################################################
##########################################################################################################
##########################################################################################################

define("CLIENT_ID", $CLIENT_ID);
define("CLIENT_SECRET", $CLIENT_SECRET);

//define("URI_LIVE", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/");
define("URI_LIVE", "https://api.paypal.com/v1/");


class paypal{
    private $access_token;
    private $token_type;
    /**
    * Constructor
    *
    * Handles oauth 2 bearer token fetch
    * @link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers
    */
    public function __construct($code=''){
        $postvals = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=".$code."&redirect_uri=https://biddingblock.com/api/seller.htm";
        $uri = URI_LIVE . "oauth2/token";
        $auth_response = self::curl($uri, 'POST', $postvals, true);
        $this->access_token = $auth_response['body']->access_token;
        $this->token_type = $auth_response['body']->token_type;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function getInfo(){
        $uri = URI_SANDBOX . "identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid";
        return self::curl($uri, 'GET');
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
    * cURL
    *
    * Handles GET / POST requests for auth requests
    * @link http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
    */
    private function curl($url, $method = 'GET', $postvals = null, $auth = false){
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        //if we are sending request to obtain bearer token
        if ($auth){
            $headers = array("Accept: application/json", "Accept-Language: en_US");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, CLIENT_ID . ":" .CLIENT_SECRET);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            //if we are sending request with the bearer token for protected resources
        } else {
            $headers = array("Content-Type:application/json", "Authorization:{$this->token_type} {$this->access_token}");
        }
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
        );
        if ($method == 'POST'){
            $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postvals;
            $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = $method;
        }
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
//      showMe($response);
        $header = substr($response, 0, curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
        $body = json_decode(substr($response, curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)));
        curl_close($ch);
        return array('header' => $header, 'body' => $body);
    }
}

##########################################################################################################
##########################################################################################################
##########################################################################################################


showMe('We\'ve Got More Milk!');

showMe($_GET);

showMe('We\'ve Got Access!');

$code = $_GET['code'];
$z = new paypal($code);
showMe($z);


showMe('We\'ve Got Info!');

$zz = $z->getInfo();

showMe($zz);
```

---

This properly gets an access token, but when I when I send the access token to retrieve the email and account status it does not return the email or account status as requested.

((it is disclosed to client when they use the "login with PayPal box on our site))

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Manta,

The only problem I am able to see is on this line:

```
$uri = URI_SANDBOX . "identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid";
```

I don't see URI_SANDBOX declared and it looks like you are using URI_LIVE as you are testing on live.

Changing this has resolved the issue in my copy of your code.

Comment: I forgot to thank you Aaron, and my GrandDad taught me that late is better than never so  THANK YOU  :-)